# Bash (.sh) file not generating any output as same as terminal command in Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, terminal

need help! I have write the following Ubuntu terminal command as below and generate the output. Now I want to do the same by writing the (.sh) script check below:

```
Ubuntu terminal command:

sudo journalctl | grep -E 'authentication failure' | grep -E 'testusr1' | more
```

```
Output:
Jul 05 13:44:56 khUbuntu su[20464]: pam_unix(su-l:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=0 tty=pts/1 ruser=kh rhost=  user=testusr1
Jul 05 14:56:44 khUbuntu su[23766]: pam_unix(su-l:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=0 tty=pts/2 ruser=kh rhost=  user=testusr1
```

Then I have write the following `word.sh` (shell script) but it's not generating any output like the above terminal command, what's I am writing wrong??

```
#!/bin/bash

# User input:
echo "Enter what you want to Search : "
read inputword

#userinput="authentication failure AND testusr1"

b=$(echo ${inputword%*AND*})   # remove AND from the inputword and get 'authentication failure'
length=${#b}
echo "$length" # get the length of b
removeBack1=${b%%*( )} #remove any white space from tail
length=${#removeBack1} #check length again to verify with the top lenth $b
echo "$length"
echo "This is 1st value:$removeBack1"

a=$(echo ${inputword#*AND})    # removing word AND from inputword and get 'testusr1'
length=${#a}
echo "$length"
removeBack2=${a%%*( )}
length=${#removeBack2}
echo "$length"
echo "This is 2nd value:$removeBack2"

## --- This is not generating any output -----------
sudo journalctl | grep -E '$removeBack1' | grep -E '$removeBack2' | more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to have variables, not string literals in the last command:

```sh
sudo journalctl | grep -E "$removeBack1" | grep -E "$removeBack2" | more
```

Notice the change of single quotes to double quotes - single treats string as raw, while double expands variables.